# How do I to successfully build angular 2 without magic tools like Angular CLI

Tags: angular

I've had a working Angular 2 application since Beta. Things were rather straightforward early on, with the build process mostly being a loading of various script files and referencing them.

With systemjs, things have grown more steadily complicated. Every tutorial and guide out there basically recommends you copy the entirety of the node_modules/@angular folder.

There's so much unnecessary junk in there though that I'm trying to avoid that. I'm trying to understand all the individual components involved so I can cleanly structure my build process without requiring tools to "magically" handle it for me.

I thought the bundles in @angular/bundles would solve this for me, where I can copy those over to my build directory and reference them in the systemjs configuration file and be dandy. That doesn't seem to be the case, however.

A whole other can of worms is opened when you also try doing the same for RXJS, which angular is dependent on. So that's another entire folder that I'm encouraged to copy over entirely.

Is the bootstrapping and module loading process really so complex that we should be encouraging developers to rely on carefully crafted seed libraries or tools like angular-cli, without themselves fully understanding how everything is integrated and loaded?

Comment: This is very much true in the world of JavaScript. Contemporary tools are very hard to (if not impossible) to learn due to their complexity, diversity and awkward API. To achieve task like bundling typically involves a lot of copy pasting of configuration code.

Comment: the reason it seems so complex is because various modules  are dependent upon another module which which feel like unnecessary junk (but is not). That's where tools like angular-cli comes in; structuring your app and let us concentrate on building app rather then concentrating on integrating dependencies, module loading etc

Comment: Most node_module folders contain all sorts of dev related stuff that isn't necessary for the end user consuming the library. That's why there are usually folders and stuff you can specifically copy over in a build process but ignore the rest. There doesn't seem to be any clear cut way to do that with angular and rxjs.

Comment: How about npm install --production?

Comment: I notice you got no response here, so am adding one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to build Angular 2. Tooling is one of those things that tends to drift slowly over time. There are starter projects that will get you going, but it is useful to be able to build your tools yourself, without relying on magic, even if you ultimately end up on the happy-path with `ng-cli`.

Here are the things  you will need:

### Node / NPM

Node is JavaScript that runs in your command line. It's the platform on which pretty much everything else is built.

It comes with a package manager called NPM, which we use to install the other dependencies.

Create a new folder to house your project. Navigate to it, and type:

```
npm init
```

to initialise a new project.

Node projects are insanely low-tech. The project will consist of a folder with a `package.json` file inside it. Package.json simply defines the project name, description, dev scripts and dependencies. This is all you need. The rest is up to you.

### Webpack

Webpack is a JavaScript module builder with additional capabilities. Point it at a root file, then require other files, and they will be bundled into a tree of managed dependencies.

Webpack has loaders which will let it interact with other file types, notably TypeScript and SASS.

It's an npm install. Get the command line tool with:

```
npm install webpack -g
```

Then for good measure, install a local copy in your project directory:

```
npm install webpack --save-dev
```

### TSC (TypeScript Compiler)

This transforms TypeScript into regular JavaScript. Again, it's an npm install.

```
npm install tsc --save-dev
```

and for good measure, because we might want the command line tool from outside a project directory later:

```
npm install tsc -g
```

### TypeScript-loader

Now you need to connect TypeScript to Webpack. You do this with a loader. The standard adapter is called typescript-loader, but there are others.

```
npm install typescript-loader --save-dev
```

### webpack.config.js

You'll need some config files in the root folder of your project. webpack.config.js tells webpack how to build. Here's a micro version that just points at app.js and builds app.build.js, using the typescript-loader for compilation.

```
module.exports =  {
  entry: {
    app: "./app/app.ts"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "./app.build/app.build.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['typescript-loader'],
        tsconfig: './tsconfig,json'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

### tsconfig.json

Now you need some Angular specific instructions to tell TypeScript how to build Angular code. You'll need to tell it about decorators, and tell it to preserve typing information.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

### Typings

Typings let the TSC compiler work with JavaScript libraries. You can use `typings` to manage them, or you can just stick them in a directory.

Get your typings here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html

### Running it

Because we have webpack, you should be able to just run:

```
webpack -wd
```

in the root of the project.

### Done?

There's going to be a lot of debugging here. It'll take a while to get this right. Also, your build tools will change over time, and you'll want to stay up to date.

This list was current in June 2017, but will probably be out of date pretty quickly.

That should be enough for a minimal stack. There's a lot more we might want to build into this. We might also want:

- Tests with Karma
- SASS, built with Webpack
- Separate vendor.js and polyfills.js
- Livereload, probably with live-server
- NPM convenience scripts
- Code Generation with Yeoman

### All this will change...

Webpack is the current best build tool, but there will be others. Before Webpack, we had Gulp, Browserify, Grunt, even RequireJS. They all did their own things, and had their own configuration. Manually keeping a toolchain up to date can take up a not-inconsequential fraction of your day.

This is why we have tools like @angular/cli, which is a community effort to produce a really nice toolchain that does all the above and more. It's really fast, and it hardly ever crashes.

Building your own toolchain is rather like building your own lightsabre though. Sure, you can buy a lightsabre off the shelf, but to be a real Jedi, you must know how to construct your own.